# Mapping a Python dict to a Polars series

Tags: python-polars

In Pandas we can use the `map` function to map a dict to a series to create another series with the mapped values. More generally speaking, I believe it invokes the index operator of the argument, i.e. `[]`.

```py
import pandas as pd

dic = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c' }

pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]).map(dic) # returns ["a", "b", "c", NaN]
```

I haven't found a way to do so directly in Polars, but have found a few alternatives. Would any of these be the recommended way to do so, or is there a better way?

```py
import polars as pl

dic = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c' }

# Approach 1 - apply
pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]).apply(lambda v: dic.get(v, None)) # returns ["a", "b", "c", null]

# Approach 2 - left join
(
    pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .alias('key')
    .to_frame()
    .join(
        pl.DataFrame({
            'key': list(dic.keys()),
            'value': list(dic.values()),
        }),
        on='key', how='left',
    )['value']
) # returns ["a", "b", "c", null]

# Approach 3 - to pandas and back
pl.from_pandas(pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]).to_pandas().map(dic)) # returns ["a", "b", "c", null]
```

I saw [this answer on mapping a dict of expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73702931/how-to-map-a-dict-of-expressions-to-a-dataframe) but since its chains `when/then/otherwise` it might not work well for huge dicts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update 2023-03-20

Polars has a dedicated `map_dict` expression. Use this.

## Old answer

Mapping a python dictionary over a polars Series should always be considered an anti-pattern. This will be terribly slow and what you want is semantically equal to a join.

Use joins. They are heavily optimized, multithreaded and don't use python.

### Example

```py
import polars as pl

dic = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c' }

mapper = pl.DataFrame({
    "keys": list(dic.keys()),
    "values": list(dic.values())
})

pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]).to_frame("keys").join(mapper, on="keys", how="left").to_series(1)
```

```
Series: 'values' [str]
[
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"
    null
]
```

Comment: you can construct mapper as `mapper=pl.DataFrame([{'keys':x, 'values':y} for x,y in dic.items()])` for a slight performance boost.

Answer (score 6):

Since version `0.16.3` Polars has the `Expr.map_dict` [method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html) and since `0.16.7` the `Series.map_dict` [method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.map_dict.html#polars.Series.map_dict) which can be used as folows:

```python
import polars as pl

mapping_dict = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"}

# pl.Series.map_dict
pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]).map_dict(mapping_dict)

# pl.Expr.map_dict
pl_df = pl.Series(name="to_map_col", values=[1, 2, 3, 4]).to_frame()

pl_df.with_columns(pl.col("to_map_col").map_dict(mapping_dict))
```

Comment: The method map_dict() has been deprecated since 0.19.16 and recommends to use replace() method. Not sure how it can be used though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Polars is an awesome tool but even awesome tools aren't meant for everything and this is one of those cases.  Using a simple python list comprehension is going to be faster.

You could just do:

```
[dic[x] if x in dic.keys() else None for x in [1,2,3,4]]
```

On my computer, the timing of that, using `%%timeit` is 800ns

In contrast to

```
pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]).to_frame("keys").join(pl.DataFrame([{'keys':x, 'values':y} for x,y in dic.items()]), on="keys", how="left").to_series(1)
```

which takes 434µs.

Notice that the first is measured in nanoseconds whereas the second is in microseconds so it's really 800ns vs 434000ns.

Comment: I don't think this scales though. I image OP having much more rows than give in this MWE.

Comment: @ritchie46 yeah I suppose. I just thought it odd that they wanted their output to be a standalone series.